# Difference in NumPad processing in Linux vs Windows

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, numlock

On my Windows 8.1 machine if `NumLock` is `ON` and I press

```
Shift+KP_1
```

Then `KP_1` acts as `KP_End` as it logically should.

But in Linux(Manjaro/Fedora/Ubuntu/MX Linux) if `NumLock` is `ON` and I press

```
Shift+KP_1
```

It still acts as `KP_1` and not as `KP_End`.

**Why is there a difference in behaviour ?**

**How do I get the numpad keys to act as `End, Home, etc` when NumPad is `ON` and `Shift` is pressed ?**

Edit:
VBox messes up the keystrokes. Don't use a tiling WM in VBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Windows thing and some one might argue that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> should behave like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> and highlight from cursor to end of line instead. So, it all depends on your DE (Desktop Environment) and your applications.

**KDE**

```
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Advanced -> Miscellaneous compatibility options
-> Num Lock on: digits; Shift for arrows keys. Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)
```

**Gnome**

```
gnome-tweaks (Tweaks) -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Miscellaneous compatibility options
-> Num Lock on: digits; Shift for arrows keys. Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)
```

**X11**

```
man xkeyboard-config

numpad:microsoft Num Lock on: digits; Shift for arrow keys. Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)
```

`setxkbmap -option numpad:microsoft`

Comment: Did you try the KDE option? Don't try the **X11** option in a DE because a DE would mostly overwrite X11 options. I use Arch Linux and KDE, I tested it in `kedit` and it worked. Not all applications would respect this behavior. Is it a bug? May be.

Comment: @ng.newbie, In KDE, did you test it in kate and that didn't work? mine is kate version 19.12.2

Comment: sorry I said `kedit` before but I meant `kate`.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. The culprit was VirtualBox. It works fine. I am accepting the answer. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Not at all. Glad to hear your problem is solved.